# Crawler & Scraper using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to crawl in an intranet URL, so I can get the excel automatically select one of the options from a dropdown menu, then enter a value in a text box, then click on Find to get redirected to another page, where I want to get a value copy to another worksheet in the same workbook, I have created the below, but the code is not working, saying object  required. :(

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1", Sheets("sheet1").Cells.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
        ie.Visible = True
        ie.Navigate ("https://gcd.ad.plc.cwintra.com/GCD_live/login/login.asp")
        Do
            If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
                ie.Visible = False
                Exit Do
            Else
                DoEvents
            End If
        Loop

        ie.Document.forms(0).all("txtUsername").Value = ""
        ie.Document.forms(0).all("txtPassword").Value = ""
        ie.Document.forms(0).submit
        ie.Visible = True

        Appliction.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

        DoEvents

    For Each cell In rng

        ie.Navigate ("https://gcd.ad.plc.cwintra.com/GCD_live/search.asp")

        DoEvents

        ie.Document.getElementById("cboFieldName").selectedIndex = 6
        ie.Document.getElementById("txtFieldValue").Select
        SendKeys (cell.Value)

        DoEvents

        ie.Document.getElementById("cmdFind").Click

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Please indicate the line it occurs on and the exact error message

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Nick McDermaid: in the line where Application wait,

and it it stucks on the page before the search page, it doesnt even go to the search URL

Comment: Can you edit the code and actually show it in the code? Add a comment that shows where the error is thrown

Comment: Put option explicit at the top of your module. You have missing declarations (At least one anyway).

Comment: You have mispelt Appliction should be   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

Comment: @Nick, 

Appliction.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

Comment: And don't forget your IE.Quit line

Comment: @QHarr, Thank you so much, for this, yes the Application wait time was mispelt, and now I am being directed to the search page, however its still noot selecting the option from the dropdown menu, and getting the same error but in the below line 

 ie.Document.getElementById("txtFieldValue").Select

Comment: Not sure at present as webpage doesn't display for me using https://gcd.ad.plc.cwintra.com/GCD_live/login/login.asp      <= is that correct? Is this an internal site?

Comment: yes its an internal site :(

however the elements I did include in the code are from the inspect of the page

Comment: Start troubleshooting. It seems like it _can_ find `cboFieldName` OK because it got past that right? Whats different between `cboFieldName` and `txtFieldValue`? Try some other fields and experiment. Basic troubleshooting.